# What is the correct way to import an external module when using this in my own module?

Tags: python, python-import, enthought, python-module, pythonpath

```
#SteeringParams.py
import csv

def GetSteeringParams(x):
    steeringdict = {'steeringsymbol':'steeringparam'}
    with open("/Users/xyz/Documents/CI-data/steeringdict.csv","r") as paramsfile:
        paramline = csv.reader(paramsfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in paramline:
            if len(row) > 0:
                steeringdict[row[0]] = row[1]                                             
        paramsfile.close()
        return steeringdict
if __name__ == "__main__":
        print GetSteeringParams(0)
```

This code imports a set of steering parameters into a dictionary. Works like a champ.
Next thing I want to do is to import this as a module as follows:

```
import csv
from SteeringParams import *

print GetSteeringParams(0)
```

And it returns:

> NameError: global name 'csv' is not defined

Both scripts run from the same directory. Even though I am (also) globally importing csv I am getting this NameError returned. How is this explained and what should be done to import and run “SteeringParams.py” as a module ?

Comment: Why do you have the `if __name__ == "__main__":` inside that function?  Try removing that and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Apologies @Nick, that should be outside of that function and meanwhile I have corrected it. The reason it is there is just to proof that the function produces the expected results.

Comment: I'm suspect it's a double import issue since you're importing `csv` in both modules.  `SteeringParams.csv` replaces `my_main.csv`, and `SteeringParams.csv` is empty at the time of import (because `csv` was already imported).  2 things to try, only import csv in `SteeringParams.py` or only import the the function like this `from SteeringParams import GetSteeringParams`.

Comment: Thanks @Nick for the hints. I did find that <import csv> must be in the module and is not required in the main script where the import occurs. Meanwhile, while trying several scenarios,  I am beginning to believe that I should look for a solution in the area of making sure that the module "SteeringParams.py" , which is stored in directory <my_modules>, is indeed in the PYTHONPATH. I created a .pth file <my_modules_reference.pth> in the directory </Users/xyz/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages> that only contains the line </Users/crooner/my_python/my_modules>. It seems to do the trick.

Comment: One more thing: I am using Enthought's Canopy as my IDE script editor and debugger. In order to load the edited version of a Module, it turns out that the Python kernel needs restarting each time before calling in a Module after an edit. (For files containing a main script restarting is not required).

Comment: Re need to restart kernel (or reload module): this is a feature of ipython / jupyter. See https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart.

Comment: Re "double import". There is no such thing in Python. You can do an import as many times as you like in a program. Only the first time actually does anything with the module. It puts a reference to the imported module in `sys.modules`. Any subsequent import simply references that already existing import (making the module name or its imported attributes available in the namespace where your most recent import occurred.)

Comment: Oh yes, I was thinking circular import